# how to access pillar data with variables?

Tags: jinja2, salt-stack

I have a pillar data set like this;

```
vlan_tag_id:
  nginx: 1
  apache: 2
  mp: 3
  redis: 4
```

in the formula sls file I do this;

```
{% set tag = pillar.get('vlan_tag_id', 'u') %}
```

so now I have a variable `tag` which is a dictionary `{'apache': 2, 'nginx': 1, 'redis': 4, 'mp': 3}`

At run time I pass a pillar data `app` whose value will be either

```
1. apache
2. nginx
3. redis
4. mp
```

so if at run time I pass `apache` I want to something which will get me the value `2`

I cant do `{{ salt['pillar.get']('vlan_tag_id:app', '')}}` because app itself is a variable.

I tried doing {{ salt'pillar.get'}}, but it throws error.

how can I do this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `tag` is just another dictionary, you can do a get on that as well:

```
{%- set tag = pillar.get('vlan_tag_id', 'u') %}
{%- set app = pillar.get('app') %}
{{ tag.get(app) }} # Note lack of quotes
```

If you want to use the colon syntax, you can append the contents of `app` to the key string:

```
{%- set app = pillar.get('app') %}
{{ salt['pillar.get']('vlan_tab_id:' + app) }}
```

I find it simpler to follow if I alias pillar.get and break it up a bit:

```
{%- set pget = salt['pillar.get'] %}
{%- set app = pget('app')         %}
{%- set tag = pget('vlan_tag_id') %}
{{ tag.get(app) }}
```